# how move an editText further up when sof keyboard opens?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a `editText` control in my Android View.

The soft keyboard is opened when the user click on the `editText`, but then the keyboard covers half of the `editText`.

How can I move the `editText` a few pixels up?

I have used

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

already.

I just want to adjust it further up a bit.

Comment: put it in a scrollview and scroll it up a bit

Comment: @tyczj too complicated and would be hard to implement on different screen sizes

Comment: I always thought that android does that for you automatically if the keyboard is covering up the editText

Comment: more complicated than moving an edittext up a certain number of pixels??? you are going to have the same problems doing it that way or using a scrollview, at least with a scrollview you dont have to worry about your view elements shifting. in the scrollview all you ahve to do is use the `scrollTo` method giving the x/y o9f the edit text

Comment: Maybe an easy way to do it is to set one of the widgets above it to VISIBLE.GONE, while the KB is up?

Comment: is there any "offset" property to use?